# How can i make a custom UIButton so that it has irregular curves like a rock,stone,tree ...etc?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton, custom-controls

I wanna to make a button so that it has the shape of a stone/ rocket (i.e. irregular shape not a rectangle, square ... etc) 
, i wanna to make it also highlighted/bordered with the same shape , i tried a `UIButtonTypeCustom` but it did not give me what i want .. so anyone has any help or idea, don't be skimpy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using UIButtonTypeCustom you must provide the assets for each state of your button.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIButtonTypeCustom` but also add your custom assets for the look of the button.
Typically you will set the background image of the UIButton to some image you want (your rock, rocket, etc) for each state of the button (Normal, Highlighted, Disabled…).

Simply add the images in your Xcode project, then set the background image for each state of your UIButton directly in your XIB (using the Object Inspector panel on the right), or via code using the `setBackgroundImage:forState:` method.

Comment: thanks, Ali it's not the state i mentioned before, i already did these steps before but i mean the actual shape of the button not its background :)

Comment: Normally only the parts of the background image that are not fully transparent are tappable. If you still want more customizable shape and hit testing, simply implement the hit testing methods on a subclass of UIButton. see UIView documentation and Event Programming Guide in Apple doc for those.

Comment: i think you are right this way should work , subclassing UIButton is a solution i thought of , but i asked for a general solution for this task that will fit any shape whatever it was, as example, body organs should take different shapes and it's not a logical solution to have a subclass UIButton for every organ , but still your answer would solve the problem , thanks :)

Comment: You might want to look at this github project https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton